# Oracle creating a table

Tags: oracle

How should we create a table which has a column as the average of the totals present in previous columns?
For ex :Departments  (depno,depname,noofempl,totalsal,avgsal)

here value in avgsal must be (totalsal/noofempl)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Oracle 11 you might use [virtual columns](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/VirtualColumns_11gR1.php) otherwise you can create a view that selects all your table columns and adds the average column

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENTS
(
  DEPNO...
  DEPNAME...
  noofempl...
  totalsal...
);

CREATE VIEW VW_DEPARMENTS AS
SELECT DEPNO, DEPNAME, noofempl, totalsal, totalsal/noofempl as avgsal
FROM DEPARTMENTS;
```

Comment: I want the table,not view, to have the average also

Comment: @user829310 Then you can add the average column to the table and create a trigger that updates the average every time data is inserted/updated